# How do I define a variable or recalculate it later in the code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

So the code as is will run, however the calculations for the total and average variable are calculated when the firstE-fourthE variables are equal to 0. Surely there is a way to redefine them later in the code or recalculate them? I apologize for the horrible formatting and indents, this site is very picky.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char fi = '\0', mi = '\0', li = '\0', end = '\0';
    float firstE = 0,
        secondE = 0, 
        thirdE = 0, 
        fourthE = 0, 
        total = firstE + secondE + thirdE + fourthE, 
        average = total / 4;

    cout << "This program will calculate the average of a student's exam grades." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the first initial of the student's name: ";
    cin >> fi;
    cout << "Please enter the middle initial of the student's name: ";
    cin >> mi;
    cout << "Please enter the last initial of the student's name: ";
    cin >> li;
    cout << "Please enter the student's first exam score: ";
    cin >> firstE;
    cout << "Please enter the student's second exam score: ";
    cin >> secondE;
    cout << "Please enter the student's third exam score: ";
    cin >> thirdE;
    cout << "Please enter the student's fourth exam score: ";
    cin >> fourthE;

    /*float total = firstE + secondE + thirdE + fourthE,
      average = total / 4;*/

    cout << "Student's initials: " << fi << mi << li << endl;
    cout << "Exam 1: " << firstE << endl;
    cout << "Exam 2: " << secondE << endl;
    cout << "Exam 3: " << thirdE << endl;
    cout << "Exam 4: " << fourthE << endl;
    cout << "Total: " << total << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << average << endl;
    cin >> end;
}
```

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is *not* redefine the variables, but just calculate by uncommenting the calculation code, removing the `float` declaration, and separating with a semicolon (`;`) instead of a comma...

Comment: I would suggest going through some C++ tutorials before attempting to write any more code. [Try this one](http://www.learncpp.com/)

Comment: Remove `total` and `average` from the first block of declarations and uncomment the commented-out code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired behaviour from your code, you need to calculate the total and average **after** your inputs have been populated. Assuming that the grades are whole values, you can use `int`s to store each exam result:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char fi = '\0', mi = '\0', li = '\0', end = '\0';
    int firstE = 0,
        secondE = 0, 
        thirdE = 0, 
        fourthE = 0, 

    /*IO*/

    float average = (firstE + secondE + thirdE + fourthE)/4;

    /*IO*/

    return 0;
}
```

This will provide you with working code.

We can clean it up further though.  Why would we not be able to store `John Edward Smith`'s initials as `"JES"` instead of inputting each character seperately?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string student_initials;
    int firstE = 0,
        secondE = 0, 
        thirdE = 0, 
        fourthE = 0, 

    std::cout << "This program will calculate the average of a student's exam grades." << endl;
    std::cout << "Please enter the student's initials: ";
    std::cin >> student_initials;
    /*MORE IO*/

    float average = (firstE + secondE + thirdE + fourthE)/4;

    std::cout << "Student's initials: " << student_initials << std::endl;
    /*MORE IO*/

    return 0;
}
```

That's better, the interface to the user is a bit simpler.  But what if a student took an extra exam? What if they only took 3? Either you can't input all their results, or the maths is wrong.
We can introduce a loop to the code that can handle the input of the results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    /* STUFF */

    int total;
    int exam_result;
    int exam_count = 1;
    string input;

    //this loop will capture multiple exam results (safely)
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the results of exam #" << exam_count \
                  << "\nleave blank if all results have been entered" << std::endl;
        std::getline (std::cin, input);
        stringstream(input) >> exam_result;
        if (exam_result)
        {
            total += exam_result;
            exam_count++;
        }
    } while (exam_result);

    float average = total/exam_count;

    /* STUFF */

    return 0;
}
```

this captures multiple exam results (and totals and counts them) using a safe method of handling cin
It does however prevent you from printing out each individual result before the average but you can store them in a `std::vector` and iterate through them to do that.  I'll leave that up to you.

Final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string student_initials;

    std::cout << "This program will calculate the average of a student's exam grades." << endl;
    std::cout << "Please enter the student's initials: ";
    std::cin >> student_initials;
    int total;
    int exam_result;
    int exam_count = 1;
    string input;

    //this loop will capture multiple exam results (safely)
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the results of exam #" << exam_count \
                  << "\nleave blank if all results have been entered" << std::endl;
        std::getline (std::cin, input);
        stringstream(input) >> exam_result;
        if (exam_result)
        {
            total += exam_result;
            exam_count++;
        }
    } while (exam_result);

    float average = total/exam_count;

    std::cout << "Student's initials: " << student_initials << std::endl;
    cout << "Total: " << total << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << average << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing the calculations **BEFORE** you've even got values to do the calculations with? Your code sequence should be:

```
1. define variables
2. get input from user
3. do calculations
4. present results
```

You're trying to eat your cake before you've even gone to the store to buy the eggs/milk/sugar, let alone mixing/baking it.

Comment: That's my question, how would I do that? Would I define the total and average variables after i got the user input? I'm new to C++, and my native language is python. Also my professor has a very thick middle eastern accent that can be difficult to understand at times.

Comment: well, if you want "B" to happen after "A", then you don't write your code "B->A". You write it "A->B". C++ (and Python, and any other language you'd care to think about) are NOT capable to time travel. you're doing your calculations BEFORE you have values to calculate. So rearrange your code so that time travel isn't required.

Comment: @MarcB, that's not true, in Python you can just `include TimeTravel`

Comment: @YourPalAl You can do this exactly like in Python. Variables can be declared anywhere, so long as it's before the first use of them. (Having a big Pascal-style "declaration block" at the start of a function is generally considered bad C++ style.)

Comment: I think I got confused because I can do in python exactly what you guys have told me, but I forgot you dont have to set aside beforehand the memory location, i.e you can define a variable and prompt the user for their input in one line (firstE= int (input("What was the first exam score?)")

Answer (score 0):

> How do I define a variable or recalculate it later in the code?

**Like this**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a; // define it once
    int b; // define it once
    int c; // define it once

    int total; // define it once

    a = 2; // change its value
    b = 4;
    c = 1;

    total = a + b + c; // or calculate its value

    std::cout << "total: " << total << '\n';

    a = 9; // change its value AGAIN
    b = 1;
    c = 12;

    total = a + b + c; // and calculate its value AGAIN

    std::cout << "total: " << total << '\n';
}
```